# AngularJS - Sort multiple columns including the date in string format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Is it possible to manipulate and sort multiple column in angularjs filter `orderBy`?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/br5sssv7/5/)**

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    var r = [
        {'group':1,'sub':1, 'date': '11/4/2014 2:01 PM'}, 
        {'group':2,'sub':10, 'date': '11/4/2014 4:36 PM'}, 
        {'group':1,'sub':2, 'date': '11/4/2014 8:59 AM'},
        {'group':1,'sub':20, 'date': '4/14/2015 5:54 PM'},
        {'group':2,'sub':1, 'date': '11/3/2014 9:09 PM'},
        {'group':2,'sub':11, 'date': '9/4/2014 2:48 PM'}
    ];

    $scope.mcards = $filter('orderBy')(r, [function(a){
        return -new Date(a.date).getTime(); 
        //manipulate the string and then sort it by ascending or descending order.
    }]);
}
```

It is not working as expected whereas when I try it in the following way it works great,

```
$scope.mcards = $filter('orderBy')(r, ['group', function(a){
    return -a.sub;
}]);
```

What is the problem here, am I missing something?

Comment: Any idea or help..!!???

Answer (score 0):

delete the minus symbol form return in the filter

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    var r = [
        {'group':1,'sub':1, 'date': '11/4/2014 2:01 PM'}, 
        {'group':2,'sub':10, 'date': '11/4/2014 4:36 PM'}, 
        {'group':1,'sub':2, 'date': '11/4/2014 8:59 AM'},
        {'group':1,'sub':20, 'date': '4/14/2015 5:54 PM'},
        {'group':2,'sub':1, 'date': '11/3/2014 9:09 PM'},
        {'group':2,'sub':11, 'date': '9/4/2014 2:48 PM'}
    ];

    $scope.mcards = $filter('orderBy')(r, [function(a){        
        return new Date(a.date).getTime();
    }],true);

    $scope.cards = $filter('orderBy')(r, ['group', function(a){
        return a.sub;
    }],true);
}
```

if you will sort reverse sort, add true at last param in filter

see jsfiddle update   http://jsfiddle.net/br5sssv7/6/

Comment: Thanks for the help. This code will either sort all the columns in asc or desc. But in my case, I may sort 2 columns in asc and other columns in desc.